# why my regression model predict every datapoint to the same value

Tags: machine-learning, support-vector-machine, regression

I am trying to train a SVR but I found that with some combination of features, the trained SVR predict every point in test set to the same value. this problem occurs much more when I use linear kernel than other kernels. The parameters are: C=1, gamma=0.5.
My question is what leads to this kind of problem. Is there a name for this phenomenon? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code along with your expected output.